# How Can i Reset Default Category Products Count Number?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, default-values

I don't have products in my website but Default category shows count of the products. How can i reset?

[image]

Comment: clear cache and reindexing

Comment: @GopalPatel : I did cached, reindexed, delete cache folder,, still retain the count,

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara : yes, just go to DB, truncate category related tables.

Comment: ok good. your all questions are useful to users. good going.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please goto your database through phpmyadmin and truncate the tables which are related to catagory.
2. Please reindex the data and clear cache from admin panel.

Comment: For MultiStore, i am using same default Category for store 2 , how can i reset products counts in my second store.

Comment: goto admin > catalog > manage products > here you can find the website configuration